# Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

When I used typescript to create my react project, I introduced Redux error reporting, which indicated that I could not find it, but I had to install all the dependencies.

**Here's my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "customize-cra": "^0.2.12",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

**Here's my store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import reducer from './reducer'


const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
))
```

**Unfortunately, the app doesn't compile and it complains with:**

```
./node_modules/_react-redux@6.0.1@react-redux/es/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in '~/node_modules/_react-redux@6.0.1@react-redux/es/connect'
```

What should I do is right. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try to install both redux and react-redux at same time:

> npm install --save redux react-redux

Comment: Your welcome, can you update the post with webpack configuration?

Comment: I want to find out why. I configure alias in webpack. thank you for reminding me.

Comment: `yarn add redux react-redux` for yarn package, my problem solved thanks,

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

npm install --save redux react-redux

Answer (score 4):

For people that might come across this in the future, I came across the same issue.

I was calling `connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Component)`. All I had to do was actually pass in a proper `mapDispatchToProps` argument and it solved the problem.

It had nothing to do with redux not being properly installed.

Comment: Where were you calling `connect`?

Answer (score 4):

`--save` means that dependency install as local dependency, that means related for that particular project.

`npm install redux -g` in here redux install as global dependency

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in typescript as follows:

```
yarn add @types/redux @types/react-redux
```

(or using npm try: `npm install add @types/redux @types/react-redux`)

Answer (score 0):

You my find it stupid but for my case it was: I'm working with both node project and react project opened in a single VSCODE window so i was added those redux packages into the Wrong package.json file :(