# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, docker, react-redux

I am running a MERN application using docker and I have made sure that all of my dependencies are installed but this error about react-redux module keeps appearing

here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my dependencies

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Do I need to update react version or what ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082477/module-not-found-redux,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199773/module-not-found-cant-resolve-redux-in-node-modules
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518575/redux-module-not-found-cant-resolve-redux

quick research.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and tried:

```
npm install --save redux-thunk
```